# Ionic 4 Pass Data BACK from Modal undefined

Tags: angular, modalviewcontroller, ionic4

I'm trying to create a modal window, pass it an  radio group , when a user select one value from that radio group, and then have my modal pass back the object they've selected.

radio group page and html

```
  export class PopoverstationsPage implements OnInit {

      cities :any

      constructor(public nav : NavController,public nav : NavController,public modalController: ModalController ,public router : Route) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.cities)
      }

      onRadioChange(cities: PopoverstationsPage):void {
    this.modalController.dismiss(cities);

      console.log(this.cities)
  }

    }
```

html

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-radio-group (ionChange)="onRadioChange()" [(ngModel)]="cities">
            <ion-list-header>
                <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
            </ion-list-header>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>ميناء خصب</ion-label>
                <ion-radio slot="start" value="26.2105,56.244" ></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>مطار خصب</ion-label>
                <ion-radio slot="start" value="26.161722,56.23672"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>دبا</ion-label>
                <ion-radio slot="start" value="25.615627,56.247322"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>البريمي</ion-label>
                <ion-radio slot="start" value="24.233913,55.916176"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>

        </ion-radio-group>
  </ion-list>
```

home page receive value form page above then use it in another function

```
     export class HomePage implements OnInit {

              cities :any

              constructor(public nav : NavController,public modalController: ModalController) { }

              ngOnInit() {
                console.log(this.cities)
              }

            async openUserModal() {
           const modal = await this.modalController.create({
         component: PopoverstationsPage,
        componentProps: { cities: this.cities },
      });

      modal.onDidDismiss()
        .then((data) => {
          const user = data['cities']; // Here's your selected user!
          console.log(user)
      });

      return await modal.present();
    }


async test (){

  this.https.get('weather/'+this.cities+'.json')
  .subscribe(data => {

    this.weather = data

  })


}

 }
```

l got error in console log `undefined`

Comment: Have you tried using `ViewController` to dismiss the modal?

Comment: no , modalController is required

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation? It shows you how to do it: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal

Comment: You should be able to use ViewController as an option, also `ModalController` declarations seems to be missing from your `PopoverstationsPage` constructor

Comment: it is smaller  but l dont know where is problem  @AJT_82

Comment: @fitzmode there is , but when l copied my code l missed it

Comment: Try`this.modalController.dismiss(this.cities);`, I don't see the reason to pass the `cities` into the parameters of `onRadioChange` when you have them defined on the class

Comment: it is same undefined

Comment: You're returning a string from the modal but you have this  `const user = data['cities'];`. It is looking for property of cities on the `Object` of `String` . You should log out this `console.log(data)`

Answer (score 1):

This code is working in Ionic 4.

```
async presentModal() {
  let showModal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
    component: ModalPagePage,
    componentProps: {
      selectedDay: this.selectedDay
    }
  });
  await showModal.present();

  const { data } = await showModal.onDidDismiss();
  console.log("data is  " + data);
  if (data) {
    let eventData = data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great in my Ionic 4 App.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `onDidDismiss` handler,you're logging out `data['cities']` but you're returning a `String` in the modal. This means you're querying a property of `cities` on type `String`, which is an `Object` - which is why it returns `undefined` and not throwing an error. Should be solved by the below.

```
 const user = data;
 console.log(user)
```

Comment: You can just assign it `this.cities = data` then call your `test` method. If you need more details please accept the answer and ask a different question.

Comment: okay his return with value , but still l have problem to use value return in my url !!!

Comment: when l am try to print `this.cities = data` l got `[object Object]`

Comment: l am sorry he doesn't work l  l got `[object Object]` l cant accept the answer